# Selecting part of Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm kind of newbie in Python, and I read some code written by someone experienced. This part should take part of Numpy array

```
a=np.random.random((10000,32,32,3)) # random values as an example
mask=list(range(5000))
a=a[mask]
```

For me it looks rather wasteful to create another list to get part of array. Moreover, resulting array is really the first 5000 fields, no complex selection is required.

As far as I know, the following code should give the same result:

```
a=a[:5000]
```

What is advantage of the first example? Is it faster? Or I missed something?

Comment: It seems like in the first example, the advantage is that you could've created any arbitrary list, and not just a range from 1 to 5000. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does the original code re-use this mask later?

Comment: Never use the first syntax, that's incredibly memory inefficient.  If you want to use a slice multiple times, create an actual slice.

Comment: The second way is way, way faster. But I think the point is to show that you can use a list to select indices. This list could be any thing like range(0,5000,2) to select every second element.

Comment: Just a note, if you're worried about "waste", then you don't need to set `mask` to a list. You get the same result by using `range(5000)`, and use only about 50 bytes instead of almost 50000

Comment: In the first example, it's trivial for this task but imagine if you wanted a mask for all values greater than 5, less than 112.5, divisible by 2, and between columns 3 and 17, and rows 4 and 25. All of these can be built using masking, where simple slicing breaks down

Comment: @sacul, my guess is that the range will be turned into a list (and on to an array) within the indexing call.  That indexing code is compiled, so I can't be sure.  But I think memory savings from passing a range instead of a list are illusory.  Timings are exactly the same

Comment: @hpaulj, you're probably right, I wasn't thinking beyond the creation of the mask!

Comment: But note that timings for `a[mask]` and `a[:5000].copy()` are about the same.  `a[:5000]` is much faster because it creates a `view`, not a `copy`.  The distinction between the two is important, not just for memory use and time, but for behavior downstream.

Comment: @rahlf23 : No, 'mask' is not used anymore.

Comment: @G. Anderson : You are right, but this is not the case. The code is really trivial, no filtering is necessary  To clarify: I have seen the example on Stanfor University course cs231 [see web page of the course](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/), see Assignment 1. Probably its only to show the possibility of this way.